# Can one reverse-engineer and deduce the underlying data for a constrained (max/min) optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, data-mining

If one has the result, the constraints are known, but one does not have the input data.

Comment: If I were to tell you the coordinates of the top of a mountain, could you draw a detailed map of the entire mountain (using only that information)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @whuber implied in his comment, the answer is "no"; at least, it is "no" unless the constraints are so numerous and severe that they dictate the entire data set. It is hard to imagine such a set of constraints in any useful problem.